# JavaScript Создать форму с использованием форм, составить программу поиска с использованием структуры данных – массива (простой и двоичный поиск)

Tags: javascript, html, css, функции, form

[image: 1. Создать форму с использованием необходимых элементов управления, составить программу поиска с использованием структуры данных – массива (простой и двоичный поиск); 2. Реализовать поиск числа при разделении массива на 3 части. Сравнить по времени для разных размеров массива и длины части.]

1. Создать форму с использованием необходимых элементов управления, составить
   программу поиска с использованием структуры данных – массива (простой и двоичный
   поиск);
2. Реализовать поиск числа при разделении массива на 3 части. Сравнить по времени для
   разных размеров массива и длины части.
   вот мой код html формата

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> Алгоритм циклической структуры </title>

<script src = "mylab.js">
        
</script>
</head>

 
<body>

<div id="block1">
<form name = 'alg1' id = 'algorithm1'> 
        <div>
        <label for ="name"> Количество элементов массива </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id ="a" name="input" size="16" class="display">
</form>

<form>
        <div>
        <input type = "button" value='Заполнить' onclick = "hope()"> 
        
        </div>
        <label for = "name"> Массив </label>
        <div id ="lost">
        <input type="text" name="lol" size="16" class="display">
        </div>
        <br>
</form>



<form>
        <div>
        <label for ="name"> Найти число: </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="need" name="yes" size="16" class="display">
        <br>
</form>

<form>
        <div>
        <label for ="name"> Результат </label>
        </div>
        <div id = "answer">
        </div>
        <div id="result">
        <input type="text" id = 'my_Clear' name="good" size="16" class="display">
        </div>
        <input type = "button" value='Вычислить' onclick = "bynar_search()"> 
        
        
        
</form>
<form>
        <input type = "button" value='Очистить' onclick = ""> 
        <input type = "button" id = "clear" value='Выход' onclick=""> 

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот код js

```
function hope() {
        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
        let arr = []
        for(i = 1; i <= a; i++){
            b = arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
        document.getElementById('lost').innerHTML = arr;
        
        
        }
        return arr
}


function bynar_search(){
    var list = hope()
    var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('need').value);
    let found = false;
    let position = -1;
    let index = 0;
    var b = 0;
 
    while(!found && index < list.length) {
        if(list[index] == number) {
            found = true;
            position = index;
            
        } else {
            index += 1;
        }
    }
    b = position
    if (b>=0){
        b = 'Да'
    }else{
        b = 'Нет'
    }
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = b;
}

document.getElementById("clear").onclick = function(e) {
  
  document.getElementById("my_Clear").value = "";
}
```

С чем мне нужно помочь?
Я создал две функции:

1. Первая функция считывает данные введёные пользователем, по поводу количества элементов в массиве и выводит на экран эти случайные элементы массива.
2. Вторая функция реализует бинарный поиск введёного пользователем элемента массива и выводит в результате есть данный элемент в этом массиве, или же нет. Проблема в том, что я так и не понял, как во вторую функцию вызвать значение массива из первой функции, чтобы произвести бинарный поиск. Всё что более менее я смог сделать это вызвать во второй функции первую функцию, но поэтому элемент будет искаться в совершенно новом массиве, так что прошу помочь именно с этим вопросом.
   Если не трудно могли бы ещё помочь реализовать эффективное очищение всех текстовых строк и выход из данной программы.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял. Но думаю так

```
bynar_search(hope())
```

```js
function hope() {
        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
        let arr = []
        for(i = 1; i <= a; i++){
            b = arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
        document.getElementById('lost').innerHTML = arr;
        
        
        }
        return arr
}


function bynar_search(list){
    var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('need').value);
    let found = false;
    let position = -1;
    let index = 0;
    var b = 0;
 
    while(!found && index < list.length) {
        if(list[index] == number) {
            found = true;
            position = index;
            
        } else {
            index += 1;
        }
    }
    b = position
    if (b>=0){
        b = 'Да'
    }else{
        b = 'Нет'
    }
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = b;
}

document.getElementById("clear").onclick = function(e) {
  
  document.getElementById("my_Clear").value = "";
}
```

```html
<h2> Алгоритм циклической структуры </h2>

<div id="block1">
<form name = 'alg1' id = 'algorithm1'> 
        <div>
        <label for ="name"> Количество элементов массива </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id ="a" name="input" size="16" class="display">
</form>
<form>
        <div>
        <input type = "button" value='Заполнить' onclick = "hope()"> 
        
        </div>
        <label for = "name"> Массив </label>
        <div id ="lost">
        <input type="text" name="lol" size="16" class="display">
        </div>
        <br>
</form>
<form>
        <div>
        <label for ="name"> Найти число: </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="need" name="yes" size="16" class="display">
        <br>
</form>
<form>
        <div>
        <label for ="name"> Результат </label>
        </div>
        <div id = "answer">
        </div>
        <div id="result">
        <input type="text" id = 'my_Clear' name="good" size="16" class="display">
        </div>
        <input type = "button" value='Вычислить' onclick = "bynar_search(hope())"> 
</form>
<br/>
<input type = "button" value='Очистить' onclick = ""> 
<input type = "button" id = "clear" value='Выход' onclick=""> 

</div>
```